# IoT API for uploading images/videos and viewing them via smartphone app

Tags: android, iphone, web-services, raspberry-pi, iot

I have setup a raspberry pi to capture images periodically. Currently I am syncing these images to my personal Google Drive account. This way I can watch the latest picture on my smartphone.

I am wondering if there is a ready-to-use web service (provided by some company) that allows me to upload images/videos and to see them using a ready-to-use app for my smartphone without using the more generic Google Drive app. Can you recommend a service? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Am not sure about any web services to upload images into google drive.I think,you may go with cron job to upload the images.

Writing a auto script and execute it continuously.

Refer here : https://cron-job.org/en/